# Visualize UI Validation Errors on Controls using MVVM CommunityToolkit

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, winui-3, community-toolkit-mvvm

I am trying to implement UI Validation using ObservableValidator from the CommunityToolkit to highlight controls and show error messages when they appear. From the docs I could only find on how to implement the required attributes for the ViewModel, not the Xaml part itself, so I suppose it should work out of the box. I have broken down the problem to a simple reproducable project, here is some code (this is of course only to reduce as much overhead as possible, and only an example to showcase my problem):

View code (MainWindow.xaml):

```xml
<Grid x:Name="root">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="70" Width="150"/>
</Grid>
```

Code behind (MainWindow.xaml.cs):

```cs
public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        root.DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}

public partial class ViewModel : ObservableValidator
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyDataErrorInfo]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username cannot be empty.")]
    [MinLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Provide more than 1 Character.")]
    private string _name;
}
```

This is pretty much as simple as it gets. What am I missing, is the behavior I want really not supported or am I misunderstanding something? Help is much appreciated.

Comment: The sample code in the *MVVM Toolkit Sample App* is `ValidationFormWidgetViewModel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subscribe to `ErrorsChanged`:

```cs
public ViewModel()
{
    this.ErrorsChanged += ViewModel_ErrorsChanged;
}

private void ViewModel_ErrorsChanged(object? sender, DataErrorsChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.HasError is true)
    {
    }
}
```

You should check out the [MVVM Toolkit Sample App](https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9NKLCF1LVZ5H?hl=en-us&gl=US). It has some sample code with a custom control [ValidationTextBox](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/MVVM-Samples/blob/8963a8720dc783658e764e22629598509e044d7f/samples/MvvmSampleUwp/Controls/ValidationTextBox.cs#L20) which handles error messages by itself.

Comment: Thanks, I looked into it and could get this example to work! However, in my application my Page has a ViewModel which contains another ViewModel (for a registration form) with the validation logic. It seems that the ValidationErrors do not get notified all the way up. I want to avoid to declare all the properties on the containing ViewModel in order for the Validation to work, any suggestions?

Comment: I think that should be on another question with some code that explains what you are trying to avoid.